# Best way to create on click events for child rows in Datatables

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have a set of child rows on a datatable and each of those displays an item we have in inventory.  I want to be able to have a button in each child that allows you to pass an update to the inventory so that it's a little easier to read and display.  so the child row is this:

```
                '<table>'  + 
                '<tr>' + 
                '<td>In Stock: </td>' +  
                '<td><div id="stockval' + d.nID + '">' + d.nStock + '</div></td>' +  
                '<input id="idVal' + d.nID + '" type="hidden"  value="' + d.nID + '">' +  
                '<td>Add Stock:</td>' +  
                '<td><input type="number" min="-99" max="99" id="stockup' + d.nID + '"> </td>' +  
                '<td><input type="submit" id="submit' + d.nID + '" value="Add" ></td>' +  
                '</tr>' +  
                '</table >' +   
                '$("#submit' + d.nID + '").click(function() {' +  
                ' var UpStock = $("#stockup' + d.nID + '").text(); ' +  
                ' var OrigStock = $("#idVal' + d.nID + '").text();' +  
                '$("#idVal' + d.nID + '").text() = UpStock + OrigStock' +  
                '})'
```

as you can see, the input field has an ID of "Stockup" plus the unique id for that inventory (so item 122 has an id of "Stockup122" on the input field.  Then a similar submit button of submit and the inventory id ("submit122").  So each of the input and submit buttons has a uniqueID for triggering an onclick event then reading the data from the field so that it can be passed to the database.  but the script portion just displays as plain text in the child row.  What is the best way to generate the click script for each of these buttons?

Comment: All Forms you try to submit do the same, they just use the corrosponding item ID. The submitButton should call a function `changeItemStock( itemId, changeInStock)`. Define that function somewhere on your page, you don't have to write it for every single button.

Comment: how do you get a button to call a javascript function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to correct your markup in order to proceed.
Add a class attribute on these elements, I used `idValField`,`stockUpField`, and `submitBtn`;

```
<input class="idValField" type="hidden"  value="'+ d.nID + '">

<input class="stockUpField" type="number" min="-99" max="99" >

<input class="submitBtn" type="submit" " value="Add" >
```

Then in your jquery script which is below the body tag, add an onclick event handler for `submitBtn` class, all clicks of any element with that class will call this function;

```
$(document).on("click",".submitBtn",function(){

   // access parent tr element and find the classes
   var UpStock = $(this).closest("tr").find(".stockUpField").val();
   var OrigStock = $(this).closest("tr").find(".idValField").val();

   // add two variables 
   $(this).closest("tr").find(".idValField").val(UpStock+OrigStock);
});
```

Comment: I see, this makes perfect sense, thank you.  I'm marking this one as the answer because the find classes was just easier than finding by ID.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways that you could handle this. I'll detail two below, one that leverages jQUery and another that would just rely on a bit of Javascript.

### Leveraging jQuery Event Handlers

What if instead of manually generating these click events, you had a single generic event handler that could be applied for *all* of your IDs? If you did something like this, you could wrap all of your logic within a single event handler and let your dynamic generation just work as expected:

```
 <!-- Code for your dynamic table -->
 '<table>'  + 
      <!-- Notice the item-stock class, which you can reference via jQuery -->
 '    <tr class="item-stock">' + 
 '        <td>In Stock: </td>' +  
 '        <td>' +
 '            <div id="stockval' + d.nID + '">' + d.nStock + '</div>' +
 '            <input id="idVal' + d.nID + '" type="hidden" value="' + d.nID + '"/>' + 
 '        </td>' +  
 '        <td>Add Stock:</td>' +  
 '        <td>' +
 '            <input type="number" min="-99" max="99" id="stockup' + d.nID + '"/>' +
 '        </td>' +  
 '        <td>' +
 '           <input type="button" id="submit' + d.nID + '" value="Add" class="stock-submit-button"  />' +
 '        </td>' +  
 '    </tr>' +  
 '</table >' +   


// When you click on a stock submit button (notice the added class attribute above)
$('.stock-submit-button').on('click', function() {
      // Find the nearest "item-stock" class that wraps your calls
      var wrapper = $(this).closest('.item-stock');

      // Now use this to look up your values (via the "starts-with" selector)
      var upstock = $(wrapper).find('[id^="stockup"]').val();
      var originalStock = $(wrapper).find('[id^="idVal"]').val();

      // Update your stock
      $(wrapper).find('[id^="idVal"]').val(upstock + originalStock)
});
```

### Leveraging Javascript

Another approach would be to define your function that handles performing your stock updates and just calling that via your button click event:

```
// These each would be references to the items you want to read/update
function updateStock(itemId, stockChange){
     // Find your hidden element based on its ID
     var stock = document.querySelector(itemId),
         change = document.querySelector(stockChange);


     // Now parse the value for your change and add it
     stock.value += parseInt(change.value, 10);
}
```

Then you would just need to adjust your dynamically generated markup to include those values:

```
<input id="submit' + d.nID + '" 
       type="button"  
       value="Add" 
       onclick="updateStock('idVal" + d.nID + "','stockup" + d.nID + "')" />'
```